# Intersecting 3 tables with Spatial SQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, boundless-suite

I have three tables I need to intersect but not sure how to get the third
Heres what I have so far:

```
SELECT nyc_neighborhoods.name, SUM(nyc_census_blocks.popn_total) AS POP
FROM nyc_neighborhoods
JOIN nyc_census_blocks
ON ST_Intersects(nyc_neighborhoods.the_geom, nyc_census_blocks.the_geom)
WHERE nyc_neighborhoods.boroname = 'Manhattan'
Group By nyc_neighborhoods.name
```

I need to incorporate subway stations with in Manhattan from our ny_subway_stations table

How do you intersect/join 3 tables?

Answer (score 3):

You can just add more joins:

```
SELECT nyc_neighborhoods.name, SUM(nyc_census_blocks.popn_total) AS POP
FROM nyc_neighborhoods
   JOIN nyc_census_blocks
     ON ST_Intersects(nyc_neighborhoods.the_geom, nyc_census_blocks.the_geom)
   JOIN ny_subway_stations 
     ON ST_Intersects(nyc_neighborhoods.the_geom, ny_subway_stations.the_geom)
WHERE nyc_neighborhoods.boroname = 'Manhattan'
Group By nyc_neighborhoods.name
```